# Get shared image and title info from ShareIntent

Tags: swift, flutter, dart, share

When sharing anything, Apple will get an image and a title for the shared link. And that is quite accurate. Is there any way to get that data?

[image]

I tried using the `OpenGraph`-data and that works for some websites but not for all of them.

Does Apple provide any function to get the image and title? I couldn't find anything on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data out of the URL like this:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/") {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, resp, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        if let data = data {
            let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print(str as Any)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}
```

You can get the Title and Image From the highlighted lines in below String:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
             <html>
             <head>

EXTRACT TITLE FROM HERE --->
             <title>Stack Overflow</title>

EXTRACT ICON FROM HERE (href link) ---> 
                 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
                 <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
                 <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
                 <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
                 <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
                 <meta property="og:type" content="website" />

                 <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" />
                 <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="Stack Overflow" />
                 <meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" />
                 <meta property="og:url" content="http://stackoverflow.com/"/>

                 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                 <script src="//cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=b84e3ec1d0b3"></script>
                 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=ef9c49b839e0">

                 <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed of recent questions" href="/feeds">
                 

                 <script>
```